# Firebase looping, How can I stop this from looping

Tags: android, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to set a value change listener like this:

```
final DatabaseReference chat_ref = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS + 
  "/" + room_type_1);
  chat_ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          showAlert(dataSnapshot);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }

});
```

The problem is that, the parenthesis after the `showAlert` method keeps looping over, creating several alerts when I only want one.

**What could be causing this to loop and how can I address it?**
Your help will be most appreciated!

I am not sure where I am getting it wrong, because even this loops as well:

```
chat_ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        showAlert(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: You can expect that every time the data at the give location changes, the onDataChange callback will be invoked.  That's not a loop, that's just the way ValueEventListeners work.

Comment: but data hasn't changed in this instance, it actually shows the same data over and over again, creating alerts on top on each other

Comment: Have you tried adding logging and doing step-through debugging to figure out how the code is actually working?

Comment: What do you mean by `data hasn't changed in this instance`? Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: I understand as far as my code goes, but when I put a debugger and it moves to zzp.class  , to.class, vj.class , vp.class, Handler.java, Looper.java I do not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have those several alerts because of the way in which `ValueEventListener` works. But remember `ValueEventListener` is not a `loop` is an `interface`. Please see more details [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/ValueEventListener.html). And as you see in the offical doc, it is triggered every time the data at a particular location changes.

To solve this, just get the call of the `showAlert()` out from the `onDataChange` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've been trying to do it, could you assist me further, how can call the alert with the specific dataSnapshot , outside the onDataChange method

Comment: Sure, i can assist you. So to solve this, create a condition (`if(dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("yourValue"))...`). As it is, is called every time a change is happening.

Comment: but I don't know  "myValue", ahead of time

Comment: It was only an example. A condition is needed to call that method only once. This is whole idea.

Comment: I get it, Thank you

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you in any way, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add ValueEventListener with addValueEventListener it will fire every time value of you reference changes so showAlert can be displayed several times.

Use addListenerForSingleValueEvent: your listener will be called only once.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once